# Determinants and area under the curve

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

In our school they recently started definite integrals anyhow they just brushed formulas but I wanted to know something about them so started reading about it and I know that's area under the curve and now I have a doubt that if u can integrate by chopping the interval to say n parts by riemann sums why can't be do this by determinant approximation by taking area from the lower limit to upper limit as the vectors as column inputs of that matrix . I'm sorry if I make no sense but I can't express what I'm thinking exactly to others

Comment: if I am correct, you mean to polygonalize a curve...In theory, you'll get the answer if you consider the limit of it, but practically, computing the determinants will be of no good use. Say you have an ellipse, you can get 8 points on it without heavy computations...using them to find the area will give a good enough approximation